# Фон следующего элемента в конце первой строки

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток. Хотелось бы узнать, как решить мою проблему. Делаю меню на css. Вот исходник: http://jsfiddle.net/d2rFD/1/ Но там в конце первой строчки вылазит косяк: туда попадает фон следующего элемента, как это можно исправить?

Почему то не сохраняется css код, выложу его тут:

```
.catalog_menu {
    width: 920px;    
}

.catalog_menu ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url('http://networkcomp.ru/cat_menu_bg.png') repeat-x;
}

.catalog_menu a {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 24px;
    color: #366c08;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: CSS я в ваш пример добавил, ссылку обновил, но проблему, описанную выше не увидел. Проблема возникает в каком-то определенном браузере?

Comment: Проблема эта появляется в Опере, опера свежая...
Вот что в ней происходит
http://networkcomp.ru/im.bmp

Answer (score 3):

```
display: inline-block;
```

вместо display: inline;

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9LDx/